# How to register punch in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Does somebody know how to register punch with commands? I want to execute a function when player punch other player or mob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when player attacks another player](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226755/detect-when-player-attacks-another-player) or [A Minecraft poison sword](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/258135/185203)

Comment: Probably a redundant question, but do you want to register a punch regardless of whether or not you hit something, or do you want to register when you deal damage with a punch?